# Problem Finding Differences Between Objetcs

Tags: python, xml, parsing, math, api-design

I'm a python self student in early stages of my process. I've decided to write a code that does some reverse-engineering on Adobe Premiere's PRPROJ files. This files are gzipped XMLs, and I've managed to parse it and extract most of the attributes I've wanted to and store them in objects. I've later found out what I'm trying to do is kind of an Open Source API to read PRPROJ files. I might learn something in the way and have a lot lo learn yet, so thanks for your patience.

Now, when trying to find what the inner timecodes of Audio Clips in timelines are, I've couldn't find the right criteria to distinguish between them in the XML Code. Premiere seems to know the difference between them and I can't find find it.

My first hypothesis was the difference was about audios having embed timecode or not. My second was file formats —WAVs, AIFFs, mp3 etc— and now I'm in total blank.

Audio clips in timelines are a result of the XML different objects combined in this way:

[Object Structure in XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjv0v.png)

So I've made this Premiere Project containing different kind of Audio Clips and tried different codes to actually retrieve In and Out points for the audio selection.

[Representation of Timeline and Clip's in and outs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtdJ6.png)

I've managed to successfully retrieve 3 of 4 inPoints and OutPoints, resulting of the adding of XMLs object's inPoint + MediaInPoints and OutPoint + MediaOutPoints properly divided by the MediaFrameRate attribute corresponding (for some reason for me still unknown, some kinds use the clip MediaFrame attributes, other uses ProjectSettings' MediaFrame attribute)

**Sample 1 (.mov's audio coming from video file)
**

```
<MediaInPoint>0</MediaInPoint>
<MediaOutPoint>23843635200000</MediaOutPoint>
<MediaFrameRate>4233600000</MediaFrameRate>
```

And was successfully calculated this way:

```
cframerate = int(clip_loggings.find('MediaFrameRate').text)
cinpoint = int(clip_loggings.find('MediaInPoint').text)
cinpoint = round((media_outpoint / cframerate))
```

```
clip_timecode_in = round((clip_timecode_in / cframerate)) + cinpoint  
clip_timecode_out = round((clip_timecode_out - 1) / cframerate) + cinpoint - 1
```

**Sample 2 (mp3 file, this particular file I found it sourced its time code from Project's)
**

```
<MediaInPoint>0</MediaInPoint>
<MediaOutPoint>52835328000000</MediaOutPoint>
<MediaFrameRate>5760000</MediaFrameRate>

VideoSettings' <FrameRate>8475667200</FrameRate>
```

```
proj_fr_ref = root.find('ProjectSettings/VideoSettings').get('ObjectRef')
cinpoint = int(clip_loggings.find('MediaInPoint').text)
cinpoint = round((media_outpoint / cframerate))


for proj_frs in root.findall ('VideoSettings'):
    if proj_frs.get('ObjectID') == proj_fr_ref:
        if clip_speed > 0:
            cframerate = int(proj_frs.find('FrameRate').text)
            clip_timecode_in = round((clip_timecode_in) / cframerate) + cinpoint # Seems to be linked to Project's VideoSetting's FrameRate, Why???
            clip_timecode_out = round((clip_timecode_out - 1)/ cframerate) + cinpoint - 1
```

**Sample 3 (WAV file, '2000'is a factor I found empirically)
**

```
<MediaInPoint>472035821292000</MediaInPoint>
<MediaOutPoint>8715173208084000</MediaOutPoint>
<MediaFrameRate>5292000</MediaFrameRate>
<TimecodeFormat>200</TimecodeFormat>
```

```
cinpoint = int(clip_loggings.find('MediaInPoint').text)
cinpoint = round((media_outpoint / media_framerate / 2000))
clip_timecode_in = round((clip_timecode_in / cframerate / 2000)) + cinpoint
clip_timecode_out = round((clip_timecode_out - 1) / cframerate / 2000) + cinpoint - 1
```

**Sample 4 (Criteria Pending)
**

```
<CaptureMode>1</CaptureMode>
<ClipName>Sample 4.wav</ClipName>
<MediaInPoint>0</MediaInPoint>
<MediaOutPoint>186823687680000</MediaOutPoint>
<MediaFrameRate>5292000</MediaFrameRate>
<TimecodeFormat>200</TimecodeFormat>
```

The last, second WAV, Sample 4, I couldnt make it work, and made me realize my criteria was wrong. What Could it Be?

Please Help me! Complete information needed is uploaded to a Google Drive and is here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zbK42WFh4SN-8-ppo7QMSkTsXlZEv9MB

Comment: "I'm a python self student in early stages of my process" that right there is the problem. I'm *extremely* impressed that you've made it as far as you have (you clearly have lots of potential), but this is a pretty tall task for a novice. It's not really clear what problem you are asking about here, perhaps because you are dumping an extremely large amount of (probably extraneous) information about your task. Try to pare this down to the bare minimum to reproduce the problem you are having (dummy xml file with just enough data to show the problem, smallest amount of code to reproduce).

Comment: Thanks @JaredSmith, I'll try to simplify the code as soon as posible and add it to the drive. I didn't want to do it before because I didn't know if any of the code I was leaving behind was relevant or not :/

Regarding being a beginner, I'm trying to find some interesting course to learn to code properly : )I love logics and maths, but my main area is film editing. That's why i started my task, because of concrete interest and problem solving.